# How to get the currently showing layout

Tags: android, layout

Is there any way to get the currently showing layout without knowing its name?
I checked some posts and the solution was to use `findViewByID`, but can I get it without knowing its name?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.  This code is in my BaseActivity which extends AppCompatActivity.  You can also just put this in whichever Activity you need it in.  You can then use mContentView to do whatever you need.

```
private View mContentView = null;
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    View mainView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                                  .inflate(layoutResID,
                                           null);
    setContentView(mainView);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    super.setContentView(view);
    mContentView = view;
}
```